# Ubuntu 17.10 gnome-software process using large amounts of memory

Tags: ram, memory-usage, gnome-software

I've been running Ubuntu 17.10 for a good while. Starting yesterday (April 9) the process `gnome-software` started using large amounts of memory. I don't know if it is related to the update that I took that day.

`gnome-software` grows to use up to 7G of memory (my system has 8G of RAM.)  This expands into eating up swap and root. My root usually runs at 51% of its total disk space and it went up to 96%. System ground to a halt. Had to power off. Only after some automatic disk cleaning (?) did root return to 51% usage on its own.

This happened twice yesterday and it is starting again today.  After running only 1 hour `gnome-software` is now using (according to system monitor)
virtual mem=5.4G, Resident me=4.7G, memory=4.7G

---

*More info*:

This is continuing to happen.  The root disk space is being used in at least the file `/var/log/syslog`.  Over the last few hours it has grown to 4.9G in size.  I have to manually kill the `gnome-software` process and delete the log file to keep the computer functional.

When `gnome-software` starts using memory, the CPU jumps up and down 
from 100% to 0%.  This can be seen in the system monitor program in the resources tab. I verified this by stopping the `gnome-software` process and CPU usage goes to almost nothing.  Telling the process to continue show CPU usage jumping all over again.

This CPU usage doesn't show up in "% CPU" on the process page.  Probably due to the refresh interval?

---

*Even more info*:

This is the error that repeats over and over in `/var/log/syslog`
when this is happening. `syslog` was 1.7G when I caught it this time.

```
Apr 10 20:27:31 rwkeating-XPS-8300 gnome-software[2485]: g_byte_array_remove_range: assertion 'index_ + length <= array->len' failed
Apr 10 20:27:31 rwkeating-XPS-8300 gnome-software[2485]: Ignoring unexpected response
```

I verified this by pausing the gnome-software process while doing a tail on `syslog` and then un-pausing the gnome-software process only to see the error flooding the log.  So it is caught in this loop.  Don't know what it means ... yet.

Comment: *[Not answering the question]* For those who are using the terminal to get every package installed, it seems to be safe to get rid of Gnome Software: `sudo apt purge gnome-software`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THIS IS A REPORTED BUG ---------------------
This URL point to the bug report

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1723362

If I am reading that correctly, it is fixed in 18.04.  May have to upgrade before the official release data if I want to get any work done.

---

In the comments in the above link, a solution was provided.  I've been running this and have had no issues with the gnome-software process.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/gnome-software

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
```

Then reboot.

I am marking this answered.

Comment: Issue still exists in 18.04.

Comment: And it still exists in 20.04.